# Moving a 3D object with a mouse in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, input, mouse

I have been trying to make a whale in OpenGL. We have been trying to move the whale using a mouse input. The problem we are facing is with the syntax as well as the logic. We understand that the whale we are making is in a 3 dimensional world whereas the mouse input in in 2D for x and y on the screen.

If someone can be very specific with the syntax of using mouse input relevant to our code, that'd be great!

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include <math.h>

GLUquadric *qobja;

float movez = 0;
#define W_SCREEN 1366
#define H_SCREEN 768
#define TERR_D 75
#define TERR_W 750
#define pi 3.14
int mou_x = 0, mou_y = 0;
float alpha = 0;
float fahad = 0;

GLfloat ctrlpoints[4][4][3] = {

    { { -1.5, -1.5, 4.0 },
    { -0.5, -1.5, 2.0 },
    { 0.5, -1.5, -1.0 },
    { 1.5, -1.5, 2.0 } },

    { { -1.5, -0.5, 1.0 },
    { -0.5, -0.5, 3.0 },
    { 0.5, -0.5, 0.0 },
    { 1.5, -0.5, -1.0 } },

    { { -1.5, -1.5, 4.0 },
    { -0.5, -1.5, 2.0 },
    { 0.5, -1.5, -1.0 },
    { 1.5, -1.5, 2.0 } },

    { { -1.5, 1.5, -2.0 },
    { -0.5, 1.5, -2.0 },
    { 0.5, 1.5, 0.0 },
    { 1.5, 1.5, -1.0 } }
};

float cam_xrot = 180, cam_yrot = 180, cam_zrot = 0;
GLfloat no_mat[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_ambient_color[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat no_shininess[] = { 0.0 };
GLfloat low_shininess[] = { 5.0 };
GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0 };
GLfloat mat_emission[] = { 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0 };

// Function Prototypes ////////////////////////////////////
void drawTerrain();
void drawAxes();
//drawing function decs
void draw_frust(float inner, float outer, float height, float m_z);
void cleanup();
void camera();
void pyramid();
void draw_closed_cyl(float a, float b, float c);
void draw_whale();


/*  Initialize z-buffer, projection matrix, light source,
*  and lighting model.  Do not specify a material property here.
*/
void initLight(void)
{
    GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    GLfloat position[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 50.0 };

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
}


void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3, 4,
        0, 1, 12, 4, &ctrlpoints[0][0][0]);
    glEnable(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glMapGrid2f(20, 0.0, 1.0, 20, 0.0, 1.0);
    initLight();
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera();
    drawAxes();
    qobja = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricNormals(qobja, GLU_SMOOTH);

        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(0, 0, movez);
        draw_whale();

        glPopMatrix();

}

void draw_whale()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 2, 90);
    glRotatef(180, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(1, 1, 2);
    glEvalMesh2(GL_FILL, 0, 25, 0, 25);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    float count = 5;
    float a = 5;
    for (float i = 0; i <= 16; i = i + 1)
    {
        draw_frust(a*sqrt(i), a*sqrt((i + 1)), 2, count * 2);
        count++;
        alpha = i + 1;
    }

    //a few smooth runs
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        draw_frust(a*sqrt(alpha), a*sqrt(alpha), 2, count * 2);
        count++;
    }


    float co = count;
    for (float i = 17; i >= 3; i = i - 1)
    {
        draw_frust(a*sqrt(i), a*sqrt(i - 1), 2, co * 2);
        co++;
        fahad = a*sqrt(i - 1);
    }
    draw_frust(7.07, 5, 2, co * 2);
    co++;
    draw_frust(5, 3, 2, co * 2);
    co++;
    draw_frust(3, 1, 2, co * 2);

    glPushMatrix();

    //fin left 
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-25.5, 10, 25);
    glRotatef(100, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(135, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(1, 6, 1);
    draw_closed_cyl(0, 0, 0);
    glPopMatrix();


    //fin right 
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(25.5, 10, 25);
    glRotatef(100, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(-135, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(-45, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(1, 6, 1);
    draw_closed_cyl(0, 0, 0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void draw_frust(float inner, float outer, float height, float m_z)
{
    qobja = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricNormals(qobja, GLU_SMOOTH);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, m_z);

    gluDisk(qobja, 0.0, inner, 200, 20);
    gluCylinder(qobja, inner, outer, height, 200, 200);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void draw_closed_cyl(float a, float b, float c)
{
    qobja = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricNormals(qobja, GLU_SMOOTH);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(a, b + 2, c);
    glRotatef(120, 0, 0, 1);
    gluCylinder(qobja, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 20, 20);
    gluDisk(qobja, 0, 3.0, 20, 20);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 2.0);
    gluDisk(qobja, 0, 3.0, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
}


void drawTerrain(){
    GLfloat color[] = { 0.2, 0.8, 0.2 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, color);
    glColor3f(0.2, 0.8, 0.2); // this line is not needed when lighting in enabled
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-TERR_W / 2, 0.0, -TERR_D / 2);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(TERR_W, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(TERR_W, 0, TERR_D);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, TERR_D);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
void drawAxes(){
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(3, 0, 0);
    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 3, 0);
    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 3);
    glEnd();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(1.5*60.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1, 1.5*120.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    camera();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void camera(){
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -110);
    glRotatef(cam_xrot, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(cam_yrot, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(cam_zrot, 0, 0, 1);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    // Camera controls - Rotation along principle axis
    switch (key) {

        case 'n':
            if (movez <= -100)
                movez = movez + 100;
            else
            movez = movez - 3;
            break;

    case 'q':
        cam_xrot += 10;
        if (cam_xrot >360) cam_xrot -= 360;
        break;
    case 'z':
        cam_xrot -= 10;
        if (cam_xrot < -360) cam_xrot += 360;
        break;
    case 'a':
        cam_yrot += 10;
        if (cam_yrot >360) cam_yrot -= 360;
        break;
    case 'd':
        cam_yrot -= 10;
        if (cam_yrot < -360) cam_yrot += 360;
        break;
    case 'w':
        cam_zrot += 10;
        if (cam_zrot >360) cam_zrot -= 360;
        break;
    case 'x':
        cam_zrot -= 10;
        if (cam_zrot < -360) cam_zrot += 360;
        break;
    case 27:
        cleanup();
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void cleanup() // call once when you exit program
{

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(W_SCREEN, H_SCREEN);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the function named "jerry."

Comment: It's not needed. We were testing it for something but didn't work out. I've edited and removed it so you can now have a look at it

Comment: the idea is either to project your 3D object in 2D or your mouse coordinates into a line in 3D space, using projection parameters, and then to test intersection between them. For both, i would say that you need a better control of the matrix system